# Webview is taking fullscreen in android

Tags: android

I want to view a pdf in a Webview using the following code i am able to view it but the problem is that it opens a new view occupying the entire screen.I want the pdf to be viewed should be open in the Webview only and not in a new window.
I am using the following code:

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        String pdf = "http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf";
        String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf;
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

And following is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pdf_top_box" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_pdf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_pdf" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_layout"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What makes you think you can open a PDF in a Android WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        String pdf = "http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf";
        String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf;
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //UPDATE HERE
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```