# Webview taking up entire screen

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to implement a WebView in one one of my xml files in my android studios mobile app project. What I am trying to do is have a few buttons that will navigate through different pages that are local to the app, and have a webpage beneath those buttons. However, the webview keeps taking up the entire screen space and the buttons that I created can no longer be seen. For reference, here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".GetInvolved" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:onClick="goHome"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="572dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeButton" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is how I'm loading the webview

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        view = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView webView, String url) {
                try {
                    // remove the nav bar and the footer from each loaded page.
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:(window.onload = function() { " +
                            "})()");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }
```

I have tried several different Stack Overflow posts like this one [Webview is taking fullscreen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020215/webview-is-taking-fullscreen-in-android) but I could not get it to work. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` and `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` in the `Webview` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="572dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```